# Netbeans Tab-space setting

Tags: netbeans, bitbucket, indentation

Whenever I commit my code on bitbucket, My Tab-space indentation do not match with other Devlopers, Though Netbeans showing it with proper indentation. 
Is this problem of Netbeans tab setting or bitbucket? 
Is there any way we can provide Tab setting to change as per pulled file Tab setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably because you are using *Tabs* and the others expand those to *spaces*. The size of a tab differs somewhere between 2 and 8 spaces and this destroys any formatting.

Just set the option to expand Tabs to spaces and the problem is solved. You can use your IDE as usual, but the file will contain fixed spaces (eg. 4 spaces) instead of a hard tab ("\t").

To do this:

1. Open **`Tools --> Options`** and go to **`Editor -> Formatting`**
2. Language: *All Languages*
3. Category: Tabs and Indents
4. Select ***Expand Tabs to Spaces*** and a Number of spaces / Tab size of 4 (or whatever is used in your project)

You can check this by enabling **`View --> Show Non-Printable Characters`**. This should show bullets if spaces are used but some kind of arrow for Tabs.